# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS, I'm trying to get data from an API,the data is loaded, however when using "items.results" in MovieRow.js, I get these errors:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined.

*Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

**

Tmdb.js

```js
const API_KEY = '********************';
const API_BASE = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3';

const basicFetch = async (endpoint) => {

    const req = await fetch(`${API_BASE}${endpoint}`);
    const json = await req.json();
    return json;
}

export default {
    getHomeList: async () => {
        return [
            {
                slug: 'originais',
                title: 'Originais do Netflix',
                items: await basicFetch(`/discover/tv?with_network=213&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'trending',
                title: 'Recomendados para você',
                items: await basicFetch(`/trending/all/week?language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'toprated',
                title: 'Em Alta',
                items: await basicFetch (`/movie/top_rated?language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'action',
                title: 'Ação',
                items: await basicFetch (`/discover/movie?with_genres=28&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'comedy',
                title: 'Comédia',
                items: await basicFetch (`/discover/movie?with_genres=35&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'horror',
                title: 'Terror',
                itens: await basicFetch (`/discover/movie?with_genres=27&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'romance',
                title: 'Romance',
                itens: await basicFetch (`/discover/movie?with_genres=10749&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
            {
                slug: 'documentary',
                title: 'Documentários',
                itens: await basicFetch (`/discover/movie?with_genres=99&language=pt-BR&api_key=${API_KEY}`)
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

MovieRow.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './MovieRow.css';

export default ({title, items}) => {

    return(

        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <div className='movieRow--listarea'>
                {items.results.length > 0 && items.results.map((item, key)=> (
                    <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${item.poster_path}`}/>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**

App.js

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Tmdb from './Tmdb';
import MovieRow from './components/MovieRow';

export default () => {

  const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAll = async () => {

      let list = await Tmdb.getHomeList();
      setMovieList(list);
    }

    loadAll();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='page'>
      <section className='lists'>
        {movieList.map((item, key)=>(
          <MovieRow key={key} title={item.title} items={item.items}/>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: First Error: You are trying to access a property of an undefined value. Add some console logs to check what value are you expecting.
Second Error: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component
Also, your code spinnets are not running, try creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting undefined errors is because of the typo in the key field.

`itens` instead of `items`.

For the safer side always check for the undefined case,

You can use **optional chaining** like below.

```
{items?.results?.map((item, key)=> (
    <img key={key} src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${item.poster_path}`}/>))}
```

Read more - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

**For a unique key warning**, set a unique key for the image tag, if you are getting a unique key from the response that is more preferable.

Comment: As you said it was a typo that went unnoticed, I changed the name and used the chaining and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined.

You have a typo in your data, `itens` instead of `items`. This causes `item.items` to be undefined, and as a result, MovieRow gets undefined `items`, on which you then try to map, causing the error.

It would be a good idea to prevent these issues by null checking in MovieProp component, as well as leveraging PropTypes to tell React what each component expects, so you can get less cryptic errors:

```
export default function MovieProp({title, items}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <div className='movieRow--listarea'>
                {items && items.results && items.results.length && items.results.map((item, key)=> (
                    <img src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${item.poster_path}`} key={key} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

MovieProp.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  items: PropTypes.shape({
    results: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      poster_path: PropTypes.string,
    })).isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};
```

> *Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

You forgot to add unique `key` to `<img>` tags rendered in MovieRow component.

Side note: It's generally not a good idea to use index (2nd argument from `.map()`) as React component keys. In your case, `item.slug` might be a good choice, if you know for sure `slug`s are going to be unique.
More on that topic: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys